# Should I replace my system binary of PHP in /usr/bin with a self compiled one?

Tags: software-installation, package-management, php, path

I had PHP version 5.4 installed on my Mac 10.9 machine and wanted to upgrade to 5.6.

I downloaded the source files and ran `./configure`, `make` and `make install`. I looked and it seems to have compiled and installed successfully, but it installed itself into `/usr/local/bin`. The old version of PHP is installed in `/usr/bin`.

When I run `php`, the `/usr/bin` location is used, since `/usr/bin` comes before `/usr/local/bin` in the `$PATH`. I would like to use the new version.

Should I just replace the old version of PHP in `/usr/bin` with the version in `/usr/local/bin`? Or should I delete them from `/usr/bin` altogether?

It's a little tricky because the 5.6 install also installed some other things, like a new version of `perl` and `pecl` and a couple other helper binaries (including `php-config` and `phpize`). Some of those (the last two) were already present in the `/usr/bin` folder, but `perl` and `pecl` were not. Should I move all the new things to `/usr/bin`?

Lastly, why is it that the newer one installed in `/usr/local/bin` but the old one did not? Is the distinction important? Did the PHP team decide to move it for some reason? Or was it just in `/usr/bin` because it came with my system, whereas the downloaded update gets put into `/usr/local/bin`?

And does the location of `php.ini` depend on any of this?

Comment: Do not touch anything. Delete, move or otherwise. Why do you have the older version of php, and how you installed it? Isn't more easier just point whatever software to use the one in your /usr/local directory?

Comment: @Braiam The older version of PHP comes pre-installed on Mac OS X. Is there any reason (dependencies, best practices, n00bness) you think I should "not touch anything"? The question is more about which directory is appropriate and what the best practices are for where to put PHP (/usr/bin vs /usr/local/bin).

Comment: @Braiam Actually I was wrong - the original version of PHP seems to have been installed by me as well. So I guess it doesn't really matter. If anything's broken by moving it, I'll definitely find out! :P

Comment: Generally, `/usr/local/{bin,sbin}` should come first in `PATH`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, the `/usr` hierarchy is used for stuff coming from the OS vendor/site administrator, while `/usr/local` is used for things installed locally (for example on a network, `/usr` might be a NFS mount which is shared by several computers, while `/usr/local` is a local filesystem). This is why configure scripts usually install into `/usr/local` by default - to not break system packages. It is also the reason, why `PATH` should have `/usr/local/{bin,sbin}` **before** `/usr/{bin,sbin}`.

To change it, all you need to do (for a well behaved build system) is running:

```
./configure --prefix=/path/to/install/to
```

That saidm a lot depends what was the source of the older PHP version. Just overwriting it is not a good idea, since it may leave some files from the older version lying around (this is why using package managers is a Good Idea<sup>TM</sup>). Thus unless you have a clean way of uninstalling the previous version, `/usr/local` might be slightly better. Another option would be (mis)using a separate hierarchy under `/opt` - e.g. installing into `/opt/php5.6`.

Comment: What I ended up doing was putting `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin` in my PATH as you suggested. I also realized that I hadn't configured PHP correctly. I needed to include `--with-apxs=/path/to/apxs` when I ran `./configure` so that the `libphp5.so` would get updated. With that, both Apache and the CLI are running PHP 5.6.4.